# Newbie: Web.xml Eclipse. xsi:schemaLocation & xmlns:web

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

2.5 xsd and 3.0 xsd. Why there are 2 xsd?

```
Project Spec:
    Server info: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
     Servlet version: 3.0
     JSP version: 2.1
     Java version: 1.6.0_32


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>MyFirstApp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your autogenerator (you generate this code with?) of Web.xml choice the last and better version for your xmlns:web and for your xsi:schemaLocation.

It's not a problem to have different xsd version on 2 elements of the web.xml I think. If you have a problem go to 2.5 version.

I see you are using JSP, maybe it's better to look to JSF2.0 + Primefaces 3.2 ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will head slow from Servlet/JSP to MVC framework and Hiberante.