# Is 'xmlns:web' attribute special in XML?

Tags: xml, web.xml, xml-namespaces

A lot of examples of Java EE's `web.xml` file begin with

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" <----------
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
    id="WebApp_ID"
    version="2.5">
...
```

While I think I understand [what 'xmlns:anything' generally means](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/#ns-decl) and I suppose `xsi:schemaLocation` is just a map `XML namespace -> schema file (XSD?) URI` I don't know what `xmlns:web` is supposed to mean.

1. Is it a declaration of `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd` namespace with `web` prefix? If it is so, why the prefix is not used in most of the examples? And why the namespace ends with '.xsd' -- this being nonstandard?
2. If it is a declaration of schema location for the default namespace, where can i find documentation for this feature?

Example of examples:

- **every** 'Dynamic Web Project' created by Eclipse
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13712/web_xml.htm
- [Newbie: Web.xml Eclipse. xsi:schemaLocation & xmlns:web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829350/newbie-web-xml-eclipse-xsischemalocation-xmlnsweb)
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Wicket
- http://scn.sap.com/community/open-source/blog/2012/05/02/nw-73-spring-31-jsf-20-and-primefaces-part-2

Comment: Taking look into referenced file: http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd and it contains yet another example of `web.xml` prolog. This time without the weird line, so i assume, following @Michael Kay comment, that it was some mistake that is being copied from example to example without understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A namespace is just a string, usually in the form of a URI. The fact that it ends in .xsd probably means that the person who defined it had some bright idea about using the same string to identify both the namespace and the schema for the namespace, which might or might not be a good idea, but as far as the namespace is concerned, is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for answer. While this sounds perfectly reasonable, it does not the answer my root concern: why, oh, why people put the marked line in so many examples of web.xml?

Comment: Good question. I have no idea. It could be that they are all copying from an example somewhere. Perhaps it's used in some cases but not in this case. Does it work if you leave it out?

Comment: I doubt this to be ever used as a namespace. Why one would want to have namespace X and namespace Y where, as by coincidence, Y is the location of XSD for X? ... And if it is indeed sometimes used as a namespace, i doubt sanity of the developer doing this :)

Comment: Well, I have come across XML vocabularies where namespace declarations are used in surprising ways: for example "if the document declares namespace X then the recipient can assume that it contains no private extensions", where the namespace declaration is not used in any other way. I've no idea if this is such a case.

Comment: [Technically](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#dt-namespace) namespace identifier is not _"just a string, usually in the form of a URI"_, but required to be in the form of a URI ([IRI](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names11/#dt-namespace)) reference.

Comment: @Michał, yes i known what namespace in general is, i also gave a pointer to some docs in the question.
Michael, this is very insightful!

Comment: @Michal, the Namespaces recommendation requires the namespace to be a URI and requires parsers to report no error if it isn't. Also, Namespaces 1.1 permits IRIs as well as URIs. So in practice, the statement that it's usually in the form of a URI is fair.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing special about `xmlns:web`. It's just the declaration of the `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd` namespace, and the association of that namespace with the `web` prefix.

Comment: Thank you for answer. While this sounds perfectly reasonable, it does not the answer my root concern: why, oh, why people put the marked line in so many examples of web.xml?

Comment: Because that's the namespace the elements are in. That line defines the `web:` prefix which is used in the web.xml file.

Comment: I searched the 4 currently linked examples for 'web:' but found nothing. Can the namespace prefix be utilized in some other form?